# Why do two literal degree ° symbols compare equal in unit tests under Windows but not under Linux?

Tags: .net, .net-core, unicode, character-encoding, cross-platform

First, let me say that I understand character encodings and why the degree (°) symbol might come out as a question mark on a web page. However, I am confused why two occurrences of that literal character in code seem to not compare as equal, and one of them displays as a question mark, in a unit test but only when running under Linux.

Here's the code that should produce the degree symbol:

```
        public override string ToString()
        {
            var strLat = string.Format("{0} {1:D2}°{2:D2}'{3:D2}\"", IsNorth ? 'N' : 'S', Degrees, Minutes, Seconds);
            return strLat;
        }
```

So there it is as a literal character in my code. Now here's the unit test. This test passes when run under Windows, but not when run on my TeamCity agent under Ubuntu Linux...

```
    [Subject(typeof(Declination), "Conversion to sexagesimal")]
    class when_converting_a_negative_double_declination_to_sexagesimal
    {
        Because of = () => Dec = new Declination(expectedValue);
        It should_format_correctly = () => Dec.ToString().ShouldEqual("S 06°13'01\"");
        It should_have_the_correct_value = () => Dec.Value.ShouldBeCloseTo(expectedValue);
        It should_have_positive_degrees = () => Dec.Degrees.ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
        It should_have_positive_minutes = () => Dec.Minutes.ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
        It should_have_positive_seconds = () => Dec.Seconds.ShouldBeGreaterThanOrEqualTo(0);
        static Declination Dec;
        const double expectedValue = -6.21712739926718;
    }
```

There it is again, as a literal character, in my unit test. You'd think these would compare equal (at least, I would). But here's the result I get in TeamCity:

[image]

There's obviously some Unicode chicanery going on here, but I honestly can't see where! It's literally (pun intended) the same literal character in both strings. Why does this test fail?

Comment: What are the file encodings of the two source files? Are they the same?

Comment: @omajid I would assume so, I wasn't really aware you could even change that. I use Visual Studio.

Comment: @omajid Aha! It looks like you are on to something. Looks like one file is Windows-1252 and the other is UTF-8. I opened them in VS Code and it shows the encoding in the status bar. Just goes to show, one should never assume!

Comment: @omajid That was it. Some of my files were using Windows-1252 encoding and some were using UTF-8. I rewrote them all in UTF-8 and one of the degree symbols changed to the question mark in the source code. I then corrected that and now all the tests pass on both Windows and Linux. Do you want to write that up as a answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files must be using different encodings.

If both files contain literal `°` characters and there's a mismatch, then the files must be using different encodings for that `°`.

Can you convert the files to the same encoding.

Alternatively, you can embed these using unicode syntax for characters/strings (`"\u00b0"`) and stay within the safe ASCII range.